# Reading a blob from MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I have a problem reading a blob from a MySQL database with Java.
I need to write a webservice with jax-rs to deliver an image saved in the database. For transport, it has to be encoded using Base64.

This is my code:

```
public String getImage(@PathParam("id") int id) throws SQLException{
    System.out.println(id);
    String img64str = "null";
    Blob image = null;
    Connection conn = MySQLConnection.getInstance();
    if(conn != null)
    {
        try{
        // Anfrage-Statement erzeugen.
        Statement query;
        query = conn.createStatement();

        // Ergebnistabelle erzeugen und abholen.

            String sql = "SELECT bild FROM beitraege where id="+id;
            ResultSet result = query.executeQuery(sql);
            //Ergebniss zur�ckliefern
            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println("while");
                image = result.getBlob("bild");
                InputStream binaryStream = image.getBinaryStream(1, image.length());
                String str= binaryStream.toString();
                byte[] bdata=str.getBytes();
                byte[] img64 = Base64.encode(bdata);
                img64str = new String(img64);
            }

        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

    return img64str;
}
```

Somehow, it only returns something like this (shown result list decoded):

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@cc90a0a
```

Comment: That's the result of the call to `binaryStream.toString()`. Tip: Avoid using `String`s altogether when working with binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the "toString()" call: `binaryStream.toString();` BinaryInputStream do not implement `toString()`.
Use something like this to read the bytes:

```
int ch;

//read bytes from ByteArrayInputStream using read method
while((ch = binaryStream.read()) != -1)
{
   System.out.print((char)ch);
   // store it to an array...
}
```

Comment: @FredM can u post the complete answer here

Answer (score 3):

`java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@cc90a0a` is the result of calling `toString()` on the `InputStream`. It doesn't actually convert it into a `String` - it just uses the default `toString()` behavior of returning the identifier of the object within the current environment.

There are several `read()` methods defined on the `InputStream` interface to get at the underlying sequence of bytes represented by the stream. You'll need to use one of those to extract the content, rather than trying to convert it into a `String` via `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the result of `binaryStream.toString()`, which is something like "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@cc90a0a".

You have to use the read methods on the InputStream to get the actual content.

Answer (score -2):

This line is wrong:

```
binaryStream.toString();
```

`InputStream` does not override `toString()`, thus uses `Object.toString()`, which is defined like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). This explains why you're getting that `String`.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) shows you how to correctly convert from `InputStream` to `String`.

This said you should **not** convert binary data (like Base64-encoded image) to string (see NullUserException's comments below).

Comment: -1 For recommending the conversion of an `InputStream` to a `String`. This is a terrible idea if the `InputStream` doesn't actually contain textual data.

Comment: @NullUserException Nonsense. I'm not recommending it, that's what the OP wants/is asking for. `String getImage()`.

Comment: Well, it's wrong. This will mangle the binary data. You should be educating the OP to do it the right way, not mislead them into the wrong path.