# Storing and receving the images from database

Tags: java, jquery

I have stored an image in data base (mySql).I have taken the field type as blob and storing the image in string format.I successfully reciving the blob The response what i am getting is com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@34b7cdfb .Please can any one tell me how to convert it back to image and show it using jquery.Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get a chance to search SO . I just now searched and found : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610011/reading-a-blob-from-mysql-with-java

Comment: You need to add the code you used to encode it etc for anyone to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve an Image stored as BLOB on a MYSQL DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150265/retrieve-an-image-stored-as-blob-on-a-mysql-db)

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.This is the code i am using  object.put("img",set.getBinaryStream("img")); And the response i am getting is java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5168abd7.Now how can i convert this back to the actual image and show it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you not to save your image in the database with time it going to slow your DBMS

Comment: I got so many images to be saved how can i do this without using database.Please let if there is any other way.

Comment: you'll just create a folder in your project in which you'll upload your images and you save their path in the database

Comment: In that case the code size will become big.Does it going to effect the performance? And also if i want to add more images once the website goes live is there any way to add the images to that folder.

Comment: yes it is absolutely possible
and do not worry about the performance and code size

Comment: That's cool.Can you please tell me how to add the images to that folder without uploading the code to live again and again.

Comment: Here is a small example

Comment: Thanks ghazi.But i am doing it in java i don't know php.

Comment: I currently work in Symfony2 lol
try this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm